# In github, how does one push a local git repo to a newly created github repo?

Tags: git, github, push

I have worked on my local git project and am now ready to go public, i.e. push to github. I have a github account and created an empty repo. I start through the instructions, and get the paraphrased error message "origin main already exists". This is widely discussed and solved on Stackoverflow. Moving through the instructions, it asks for a password. I supply one and it responds (paraphrased) "We don't take passwords anymore". This too is discussed on Stackoverflow, but I did not see a concrete solution.

I did glean from the above that github now uses a *personal access token*
instead of passwords. I return to the instructions but am not given the opportunity to enter my personal access token. My question: "Given one has a github account including a personal access token, how does he push a local repo to github?

Comment: The only time you should be asked for a password is if you're using an SSH key with a password (which is not github asking, it's SSH asking you to verify your key). You do _not_ use a Github Personal Access Token.

Answer (score 1):

You can authenticate using a [ssh key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) instead of using personal access tokens.

Start by generating an ssh key by running `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "YOUR_EMAIL"`. That will generate a private and a public key.

Afterwards copy the public key (file should end with .pub) and add it as a ssh key on Github (Github -> `Settings` -> [`SSH and GPG keys`](https://github.com/settings/keys)).

You might need to remove the existing remote origin in your local repository (`git remote rm origin`), and add the new one (`git remote add origin PATH_TO_REPOSITORY`).

Then all you have to do is add the files you wish to commit (`git add PATH_TO_FILES`), write a commit message (`git commit -m "COMMIT MESSAGE"`) and push to the repository (`git push -u origin NAME_OF_BRANCH`).

If you are interested in knowing more about PAT / SSH keys the following posts contain some nice information:

[What is the reasoning behind github access tokens?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/263406/pat-vs-ssh-why-bother-with-ssh)

[PAT vs. SSH - Why Bother with SSH?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/263406/pat-vs-ssh-why-bother-with-ssh)

Comment: Note that `ed25519-sk` is only suitable if you have a FIDO2-compliant hardware key - otherwise you should use `ed25519` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you should be asked for a password is if you're using an SSH key with a password (which is not github asking, it's SSH asking you to verify your key). You do *not* use a Github Personal Access Token for standard git operations.

Check your local list of remotes (`git remote -v`) and if your origin is not an ssh URL (i.e. `git@github.com:yourusername/your.repo.name.git`) remove it (`git remote rm origin`) and then go to your project on Github, click the green `<> code` button, and copy the SSH "clone" url. Then set *that* as your origin URL (`git remote add origin git@github.blahblahblah`) .

And then follow the official instructions on using git with github outlined over on https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh. Typically you only need to read through and run the commands mentioned in https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent but if you've *never* worked with SSH before, the other articles are worth at least reading through once in your dev life.